# Load data - fields terminated by character appearing within a field statement

Tags: mysql, csv, parse

I have an issue with loading data from a csv file. The question is, without preprocessing, is it possible to have an exception in the following code

```
load data local infile 'Program.csv' into table program_table 
    fields terminated by ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
    ignore 1 lines
    (@program_code, @field_of_study, @area_of_study, @degree_level)
    SET
        program_code = nullif(@program_code,''), 
        field_of_study = nullif(@field_of_study,''),
        area_of_study = nullif(@area_of_study,''),
        degree_level = nullif(@degree_level,'');
```

that ignores the "terminate by" character when it's followed by a (space). The problem I've encountered is within the csv file there are lines like the following

```
ZLD6,Administration/Business,BUSINESS MGMT. SMALL BUSINESS, CONVEYANCING,Doctorate.
```

The `BUSINESS MGMT. SMALL BUSINESS, CONVEYANCING` should be one field, but the field termination character ','  separates int into two. That is the fields would be `ZLD6`, `Administration/Business`, `BUSINESS MGMT. SMALL BUSINESS`, `CONVEYANCING`, and `Doctorate` (5 fields instead of 4).

Any suggestions on possible solutions would be great.

Comment: It appears to me that you have a malformed `CSV` file.  Fixing the file would probably be a much more fruitful endeavor than doing acrobatics in MySQL in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but i'm in a circumstance where that is not possible.

Comment: If you cannot fix the "exporter", just create a transformation script to add `"` around what is supposed to be one field.

Comment: @jkavalik yes, this would be simple to do in java or any some other mainstream programming language, but i'm wondering if its possible to do it in SQL. perhaps its not.?

Comment: @GarrettCulos it won't be easy in SQL if it is possible at all, for the string manipulation you may write a procedure, but there is no file input/output so you would have to import it to temp table with only one column and then parse it. Do you have no access to bash/awk/visual basic script or anything? (you might even do it in javascript in your browser if the file is not too big)

Comment: So in the end I pre-processed the .csv file. Still curious if there is a cleaver way of using the `infile` to manipulate this field. But like @Erik says below, **use the best tool for the job**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question yes I'm sure it is possible to employ a scheme like [jkavalik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556/jkavalik) suggested where you:

1. Import the entire file into a single column/cell in a temp table
2. Parse the malformed csv string using increasingly obtuse trickery as each edge case is discovered.

I'm sure a smarter person than me could write an event driven, real-time, web-enabled, protocol buffer communicating, graphical user interface, autonomous aircraft landing system for use in hurricanes using only SQL, but why would they?  **You should use the best tool for the job.**  If you can't correct the csv exporter to properly escape the data then you should properly escape the data manually or use a programming language that will make this task easier.

In my opinion, SQL is only going to make your life more difficult, and as such you should choose a different tool.